# How to add search bar with bar button item, I am using core data?

Tags: ios, searchbar

I need to search trough my data that is stored in my `UITableView`. I need one left bar button item and when the user clicked that, it should show like a search bar. How to do that?.

Thanks in advance!

**edited:**

ok based on solution you provide.Here i have done some thing with search bar (bar button item). but still i am missing some thing . And also my **filter content for search box** also , having some problem. really i don't now what to do for this?

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AddNoteViewController.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "TableViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{


     NSArray *searchResults;
}


@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchBar *searchBar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchDisplayController *searchController;

@property (nonatomic) BOOL *isChecked;
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *notes;
//@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *_lastIndexPath;

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize addButton;
//@synthesize _lastIndexPath;
@synthesize managedObjectContext;


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.title = @"My Notes";

    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];


    // place search bar coordinates where the navbar is position - offset by statusbar
    self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 44)];

//self.searchResults = [[NSArray alloc] init];


    UIBarButtonItem *searchButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:@selector(toggleSearch)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchButton;



    self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
    self.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;

}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Notes"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    self.notes = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];

    NSSortDescriptor *titleSorter= [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"mod_time" ascending:NO];

    [self.notes sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:titleSorter]]
    ;

    NSLog(@"Your Error - %@",error.description);

    [tableView reloadData];
}


#pragma mark - Search controller

- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{

}

- (void) searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{

}

- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
//    [self.searchBar removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)toggleSearch
{
    [self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];
    [self.searchController setActive:YES animated:YES];
    [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}



- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Notes" inManagedObjectContext:_notes];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"notes.title contains[c] %@", searchText];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;

    NSArray* searchResults = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
}




-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
//    return searchResults.count;
    return 1;

}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];

    } else {

      return self.notes.count;
}
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell*)[aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MycellIdentifier"];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MycellIdentifier"];

    }

  _notes = [_notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Configure the cell...
    NSManagedObject *note = [self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSDate *date = [note valueForKey:@"mod_time"];

      cell.textLabel.text = [note valueForKey:@"title"];
         cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


    return cell;

}



- (IBAction)addButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    AddNoteViewController *addNoteVC = [AddNoteViewController new];

}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)cTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete object from database
        [context deleteObject:[self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
        }

        // Remove device from table view
        [self.notes removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}


-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return YES;
}


@end
```

Comment: Please add more text, info and research. Show us what you've done. We are here to help you learn, not free software support.

Answer (score 0):

use an array NSMutableArray *tempArray;

There would be some dataSource array from which u tell tableView show **numberOfRow** according to **dataSource.count**
and in **cellForRow** u display data contain in that array.
So to search u can use

```
NSString *searchTerm = @"E";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF contain %@", searchTerm];//use whatever you want for ANY SELF and searchTerm according to your need
NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
tempArray = [filtered mutableCopy];
```

and use this tempArray to display in UITableView.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly you want to add searchbar to toolbar. Here is how you can add UISearchbar to UIToolBar as bar button item:

```
// your searchbar
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xposition, yposition, width, height)];

//create a customview and make its frame equal to your searchbar
UIView *searchBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:searchBar.frame];

// add your searchbar to the custom view
[searchBarView addSubview:searchBar];

//finally add it to your bar item of the toolbar

UIBarButtonItem *searchBarItem =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchBarView];

// Now assign it to your left button item or wherever you want to add to toolbar.
```

Please provide more details in case you want any other help.